# Collapsing the width of a word-wrapped <h1> tag

Tags: html, css

So I have two pictures that describe the problem. They're below.

The only relevant css is this:

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

In example one, the title (which is an `<h1>` tag) is short enough that it hasn't wrapped. As you can see from the background color, the tag's width is only as wide as the letters it contains. This is what I want all the titles to  look like.

[image: Example one]

Here, the text has word-wrapped and the tag's width is *not* the width of the text, it is 100% of the container. (I know the text itself is *almost* the width of the container, but not quite--there's a little room)

[image: Example two]

So, I'm looking primarily for an explanation of what is going on. Is wrapped text always going to effectively have `width: 100%;`? Is there any way around this limitation?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oegmavnL/) that demonstrates the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your css to:

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cvkqq9Lm/)

Now looks like:

[image]

---

**Edit:**  Since you're not too keen in the `display:inline` idea, you could wrap your text in a `span` element, and put the background colour on that element instead.

eg:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1><span>Mine eyes have seen the glory of the coming of the lord</span>
  </h1>
  <h1><span>frog</span></h1>
</div>
```

[Your Updated JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/oegmavnL/2/)

Comment: Well, that explodes my javascript something terrible, but it does appear to solve my css problem. And javascript can be un-exploded.